# Viewport render completely different to actual render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Please see attached blend file. Cycles engine. Its a bunch of lights in a cube with a volume material. the volume is brightly lit in the viewport, while the render is black. any idea how to make the render look like the viewport? thanks, JK.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.